# Renaming folders in svn,

Tags: svn, directory, rename

In tortoise svn ,
there are 3 txt files in a folder called abc.
when I renamed the folder from abc to xyz and view the show log,
it shows only the xyz is copied from abc and abc folder is deleted
the files inside the xyz is though copied but not showing in the log.

how can i view the files when i rename the folder in svn

Comment: So you're asking to see the complete set of contents of abc in the 'files that have changed' view for the revision when you rename abc to xyz? Or something else? Why do you want this - so you can grep for history?

Comment: yes i want to view the files inside the renamed folder xyz in the svn log in tortoise svn.

Comment: Then I don't think that's possible: svn only records the folder rename in the revision.

Comment: i thought jus doing copy to and rename..but i need to for the folder and files inside the folder

Comment: Yes, I suppose if you wanted to see everything in the log then you could instead make a new folder, copy all the files into it manually then delete the old folder. But the end result - the directory has been renamed - is exactly the same, and in that case you may lose the ability to trace the history of the directory itself backwards through the rename. But why do you really need this - what are you trying to do? If you just want to enhance the log data with the contents of the directory at the time you can do that with an `svn ls path@revision`. But I still don't understand why you need this.

Comment: i need to tag the files that are been changes in between two dates, by the taking files list from svn log-modified,added, deleted will be listed in the svn log.  i will tag only the added and modified files and ignore the deleted one.

Comment: In this instance, while tagging the root directory, I lost all the files that been added inbetween the two dates, inside this renamed folder (rename was done to fix typo). Only the rename folder was shown and not the files inside the renamed folder, old previous folder was shown in svn log as deleted.                                          so in future I think I have to use copy-to option for both folder & files in it for renaming the folder. any comments from you ?

Comment: If by 'tag' you mean make a new subversion tag then don't you just want the entire folder anyway? Or whenever you see a folder copy you just need to look at the contents of the new folder using `svn ls /path/to/new/folder@revision` to get all the files, which you can do in an automated job. I don't think changing the way you rename files in SVN is the answer - instead, improve your script or whatever that gathers the changed files. But whatever you find is the best solution for you.

Answer (score 1):

You're not seeing the changes in the three files because you didn't change those files. You only renamed the directory they were in.

What would you like to accomplish? Let's say Subversion did report all files in a renamed folder as being changed. How would that help you? I can imagine a few circumstances where it isn't a very good idea:

- Imagine a situation where I started to use Maven. In Maven, my source files should be under the folder `src/main/java`. Like most developers, I had put my Java source code directly under the root of the repository under `source`. I now have to move the files in that directory to `src/main/java` which could represent hundreds of Java source files. Now, instead of my log only showing three files were changed, hundreds will be listed.
- Let's say you did modify a few files as you renamed the directory. How do I know the difference that a file was listed because some parent directory was modified vs. a file that was actually modified. People already complain that the log shows files where some property was modified, but not the file itself (which can cause problems when merges take place and the `svn:mergeinfo` property is updated). Now, each folder rename will cascade down the entire repository. Sometimes a tag is created, but the name wasn't done quite correctly (REL-1.2 vs. rel-1.2.0), so people will sometimes rename a tag. Now, all files in that tag will show up as being changed on the log?

It's not too difficult to do what you want in Python or Perl. Simply do a `svn log` and then when you see that a directory got renamed in a particular release, do a `svn ls --recurse` on that folder, and get all the files in it.